# fstream.write takes too long sometimes

Tags: c++, fstream

MP4V2 use fstream.write to write h264 data to mp4file to SD Card, about 1200KB ~ 1300KB of data every time. See code below:

```
struct timeval tv_begin, tv_end;
long int begin = 0, end = 0;
bool
StandardFileProvider::write( const void* buffer, Size size, Size& nout, Size maxChunkSize )
{
    gettimeofday(&tv_begin, NULL);
    _fstream.write( (const char*)buffer, size );
    if( _fstream.fail() )
        return true;
    nout = size;
    _fstream.sync();
    _fstream.flush();

    gettimeofday(&tv_end, NULL);
    begin = tv_begin.tv_sec*1000*1000 + tv_begin.tv_usec;
    end   = tv_end.tv_sec*1000*1000 + tv_end.tv_usec;
    printf("%s:%d sync -> time : %3ld.%03ld ms. wsize = %8lld Kb\n"
           ,__func__, __LINE__, (end - begin)/1000, (end - begin)%1000, size/1024);
    return false;
}
```

#### This is Log:

> time :  14.619 ms. wsize =     1247 KB
>   time :  15.806 ms. wsize =     1234 KB
>   time :  14.381 ms. wsize =     1244 KB
>   time :  15.080 ms. wsize =     1243 KB
>   time :  38.409 ms. wsize =     1245 KB
>   time :  22.609 ms. wsize =     1243 KB
>   time :  18.856 ms. wsize =     1257 KB
>   time :  30.591 ms. wsize =     1230 KB
>   time :  16.019 ms. wsize =     1247 KB
>   time :  14.925 ms. wsize =     1251 KB
>   time :  15.050 ms. wsize =     1233 KB
>   time : 466.793 ms. wsize =     1230 KB
>   time :  17.810 ms. wsize =     1232 KB
>   time :  14.422 ms. wsize =     1231 KB
>   time :  15.803 ms. wsize =     1221 KB
>   time :  14.874 ms. wsize =     1248 KB
>   time :  27.504 ms. wsize =     1232 KB
>   time :  14.615 ms. wsize =     1250 KB
>   time :  15.394 ms. wsize =     1240 KB
>   time :  33.018 ms. wsize =     1234 KB
>   time :  15.506 ms. wsize =     1255 KB
>   time :  15.890 ms. wsize =     1256 KB
>   time :  26.371 ms. wsize =     1251 KB
>   time :  15.305 ms. wsize =     1245 KB
>   time :  22.000 ms. wsize =     1240 KB
>   time :  23.760 ms. wsize =     1244 KB
>   time :  19.326 ms. wsize =     1254 KB
>   time :  46.003 ms. wsize =     1252 KB
>   time :  15.997 ms. wsize =     1240 KB
>   time :  14.518 ms. wsize =     1242 KB

#### Why used 466.793 ms ??

Comment: just pseudo code

Comment: There are no guarantees. The OS might be busy running another process or serving some other IO request *or* your storage medium (SD card) may just be crap and take a long time once in a while.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl:
Is there any way to speed up write?

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this issue!

This is vfs problem. I just set dirty_ratio from 20 to 5, it will work will.

`[root@elvis-g1_0:~]# cat /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
20
[root@elvis-g1_0:~]# echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio`